# Input field for address in React Native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native

I am creating form in React Native where it requires user to input school full address and check if school status is `true` or `false` in terms of boolean.

So my question is: Is there any package or suggestion to create a text input field for following info?

```json
{
  "active": true,
  "school": string,
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "string",
    "addressLine2": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "state": "string",
    "zip": "string"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native has a Text Input field for gathering info. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput/

Answer (score 0):

So for gathering info in react native we can use Textinput,to get your reqquirment:

```
<TextInput style={{width:'90%', height:45, color:'white', fontFamily:'Ubunutu',fontSize:20, marginHorizontal:10}}
                    placeholder='Address'
                    multiline={true}
                    editable={true}
                    numberOfLines={5}
                     
                    keyboardType='default'/>
```

you can check further in the documntaion...